# Reduce twice in one line in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Sorry about the confusing title, it's difficult to define...

What I'd like to do is take sequences of words as input to a hadoop job and output lines as follows:

lowercase-sequence frequency-of-lowercase-sequence sequence frequency-of-sequence

I think an example is best to explain:

Suppose my input data is:

```
the sun
the sun
the sun
The sun
The sun
The Sun
```

I want to end up with

```
the sun 6 the sun 3
the sun 6 The sun 2
the sun 6 The Sun 1
```

How can I reduce on both the lowercase-sequence-frequency and original-sequence-frequency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your map function:
output key:
sequence.toLowerCase()
output value:
sequence (as-is)

In your reduce function for each value:

```
Map<String, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
occurrences.put(key, occurrences.get(key) + 1);
if(!key.equals(value)){
occurrences.put(value, occurrences.get(key) + 1);
}
```

This is just pseudo code. You will receive NPE because occurrences.get(key/value) will return null firs time. just add checks for this.
As a result you will have map of your occurrences and counts of different Upper/Lower cases of same sequence.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew. I did something very similar to this and it worked out well.